# How to know the number of specific goroutine?

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm making a goroutine worker pool that constantly increases and decreases according to the situation.

But never falldown under specific count.

To do this, I want to know the number of specific goroutines. Not use global variable.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func Adaptive_Worker_Pool(value_input chan int) {
    kill_sig := make(chan bool)
    make_sig := make(chan bool)

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go Do(kill_sig, value_input)
    }

    go Make_Routine(make_sig, kill_sig, value_input)
    go Judge(kill_sig, make_sig, value_input)
}

func Make_Routine(make_sig chan bool, kill_sig chan bool, value_input chan int) {
    for {
        <-make_sig
        go Do(kill_sig, value_input)
    }
}

func Do(kill_sig chan bool, value_input chan int) {
outer:
    for {
        select {
        case value := <-value_input:
            fmt.Println(value)

        case <-kill_sig:
            break outer
        }
    }
}

func Judge(make_sig chan bool, kill_sig chan bool, value_input chan int) {
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)
        count_value_in_channel := len(value_input)

        if count_value_in_channel > 5 {
            make_sig <- true
        } else {
            if {            // if Count(Do( )) > 5 { continue }
                continue    // else {kill_sig <- true}  
            } else {        // like this
                kill_sig <- true
            }
        }
    
    }
}

func main() {
    value_input := make(chan int, 10)

    Adaptive_Worker_Pool(value_input)

    a := 0
    for {
        value_input <- a
        a++
    }
}
```

Some value input to a value_input channel and five goroutines that receive and output the value are created by default.

However, if the number of variables in the value_input channel is 5 or more, Do( ) goroutine will made.

I want to make the Judge( ) function decide whether to increment or decrement the Do( ) goroutine, If number of Do( ) goroutine.

How can I do it?

Comment: This looks like you are trying to reinvent the wheel. Spawning more goroutines will not necessarily speed up the process. They need some time setting up the stack and doing scheduler bookkeeping. You are better of doing tests to benchmark your use case and find an optimal max number of goroutines.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define a struct like:

```
type MyChannel struct {
  value int
  index int
}
```

and in for loop

```
value_input := make(chan MyChannel, 10)
a := 0 
for {
  value_input <- MyChannel{
    index: a,
    value: a,
  }
  a++
}
```

and in some check, you can check the `index` of `MyChannel`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).